# can't disable Step(dynamically) with Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Step button is not being disabled. I want to disable it.

```
return Object.keys(props.quiz).length> 0 ? 
        <div>
            <Steps size="small" current={0} onChange={props.onChange}>
                    {
                        props.quiz.questions.map(item => 
                           <Step key={item.id} disabled/>
                    }
            </Steps>
       </div>
```

Result below:

[image]

Comment: did any answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `disabled` attribute works fine on each `Step`

Here is an updated example with a dynamic `disabled` field in the array: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-hooks-70mpd?fontsize=14

Note  you  don't need to write `disabled={true}` as `disabled` is the shorthand. 
I presume the ** was your  emphasis and not part of the code.

Comment: yes! ** was an emphasis, but when i'm trying to use steps **dynamically** ..disabled doesn't work well, so i need to put a condition in disabled option like disabled={my_var}

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the Damian code and made it dynamic without any problems.
You can check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-microservice-51dhh

Make sure that you're using the latest antd version and if you still have any difficulties try to reproduce the error in isolation (create a project in codesandbox to show the error).